# Query from array

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql

I am getting error while trying to select values from an array, like following code

```
declare result CLOB;
  myarray selected_pkg.num_array := selected_pkg.num_array();
begin
  myarray.extend(3);
  myarray(1) := 1; myarray(2) := 5; myarray(3) := 9;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select column_value from table (cast(myarray AS selected_pkg.num_array))';
  COMMIT;
end;
```

> ORA-00904: "MYARRAY": invalid identifier

Please suggest.
 Thanks, Alan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First off, there doesn't appear to be any reason to use dynamic SQL here.
- Second, if you want to run a `SELECT` statement, you need to do something with the results.  You'd either need a cursor `FOR` loop or you'd need to `BULK COLLECT` the results into a different collection or otherwise do something with the results.
- Third, if you want to use a collection in SQL, that collection must be defined in SQL not in PL/SQL.

Something like this will work (I'm not sure if that's what you want to do with the results)

```
SQL> create type num_arr is table of number;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> declare
  2    l_nums num_arr := num_arr( 1, 2, 3, 7 );
  3  begin
  4    for i in (select column_value from table( l_nums ))
  5    loop
  6      dbms_output.put_line( i.column_value );
  7    end loop;
  8  end;
  9  /
1
2
3
7

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Now I modified my code to be 

`
    declare
    result CLOB;
    myarray selected_pkg.num_array := selected_pkg.num_array(1,5,9);
    begin
    for i in (select column_value from table( myarray ))
    loop
    dbms_output.put_line( i.column_value );
    end loop;
    COMMIT;
    end;
`

But still I am getting error 
ORA-21700: object does not exist or is marked for delete

Comment: @user2323433 - Note item 3 from the list above.  If you want to use a collection in SQL, you'd need to define the collection in SQL.  You can't declare the collection in PL/SQL.  You can't use the collection defined in the package.  You'd need to define the collection in SQL as I did in my example.

Answer (score 0):

execute immediate is not need at this point.
Use fetch or loop cursors in proc.